# Backup Incremental Postgresql PITR

Tags: postgresql, backup

Tenho uma rotina de backup incremental rodando diariamente salvando os [logs do Postgresql](https://www.mkyong.com/database/postgresql-point-in-time-recovery-incremental-backup/).

Toda madrugada é realizado o backup full:

`pg_start_backup()
tar -cvzf /usr/local/pgsql/pgDataPITR/pgdatabk.tar
 /usr/local/pgsql/pgDataPITR/
select pg_stop_backup();`

Tenho dúvida em relação a exclusão dos logs Wal, em que momento devo fazer isso, antes de rodar o backup full, ou após especificando uma data para a exclusão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resposta por: Franklin Anderson de Oliveira Souza no [Postgresql Brasil](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/postgresql-brasil)

Você pode efetuar o basebackup usando a ferramenta pg_basebackup, uma vez efetuado com sucesso ele marca o ultimo wal com a extensão .backup. Isso significa que os wals mais novos juntamente com o basebackup gerado pela ferramenta pg_basebackup lhe garante um restore consistente. Os wals antigos, ou seja, anteriores ao marcado com .backup podem ser deletados, 
para isso pode usar a ferramenta pg_archivecleanup que lhe faz esse serviço, para mais detalhes leia a documentação ou pergunte aqui mesmo na lista !

Espero ter ajudado